# Is it possible to hide Map but show only markers Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a Location based augmented reality app which plots marker on top of the camera view.

Mose of the libraries and tutorials are outdated and they are 4+ years old also not stable. Below is the link to things which i have tried and failed.

[Links to libraries](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks)

[Link to tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-augmented-reality-camera-sensor-setup--mobile-7873)

[Link to stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734587/location-based-augmented-reality-android-application)

Im trying to create something like below image which is an iOS app developed using [HDAugmentedReality](https://github.com/DanijelHuis/HDAugmentedReality) which is very stable and does not overlap.

[image: HDAugmentedReality Example]

Since i could not find any library I'm planing to use Google Maps, It rotates according to camera with simulates AR. So i am planning to show only the markers and hide the Google Map View. If this is possible i can easily create an Location based AR app..

Is it possible to hide Maps but show Markers or is there any library which i missed? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't use the Markers without showing it on Maps. The main purpose of it is to identify the location on a map. My suggestion would be for you to use your own custom overlay for the marked items you'll show.

Check out the [Sun Surveyor](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/04/sun-surveyor-brings-augmented-reality.html), its not similar to what you'll do, but the idea of overlaying the information seems plausible (as indicated on the tutorial link you provided).